# PyCharm JavaScript Debugging

Tags: pycharm, webstorm

Is JavaScript debugging powered by Firefox and Chrome available in PyCharm 1.5?

If so, can it run effectively alongside the Python / Django debugger?

If not, is there a way to use PyCharm with WebStorm in some sort of integrated fashion?

Answer (score 3):

The JavaScript debugger plugin is currently not bundled with PyCharm. Feel
free to watch/vote http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/PY-3021

There's no way to integrate PyCharm and WebStorm.

Source: Dmitry Jemerov -- http://devnet.jetbrains.net/thread/305054

Comment: Per the ticket you linked to, this was added in PyCharm 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use netbeans fully featured IDE [IntelliJ IDEA](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/), it has plugins for both web and python editing sadly it costs a little more.

You can grab the python plugin from [here](http://plugins.intellij.net/plugin/?idea&id=631), the javascript debugger is built in.

Comment: I just tried this with the community edition the python plugin does not work so you need the ultimate version.